# How to get build history by using git hub URL that used in Jenkins SCM through Jenkins API

Tags: java, git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-api

I just want to get the build execution history like Execution status, Who is executed this build (Auto/Manual), build Id, through Jenkins API for specific SCM repository.

I just want to fetch all these details based on the GitHub repository that I used in Jenkins Job configuration in SCM section.

I just need some input to kick start this requirement, and I want to know is it possible to achieve. Else Is there any other possible way to achieve this?

I'm not sure where I should start. Input will help me to get some idea.

Suggestions and inputs are welcome from leads.